# Azure Migration Assesment on Linux

Tags: linux, azure, monitor, agent

I want to test Azure's monitoring tool on linux. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-linux) document form Microsoft. I did everything exactly the same. But when it comes to restart the service, I get the [image: this error.]. 
How can I fix that?

Comment: what is the error? why do you need monitor?

Comment: For migration assessment, you can use azure migrate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-prepare-vmware

Comment: I don't use VMWare for that particular machine.